# Using REGEXP_SUBSTR as split in Oracle

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, plsql, substr

I have `A.FIELD` which outputs  the following format:

```
9:30AM - 12:50PM AbCdEfGhIj XY-000
```

I am trying to figure out a way to get each individual value based on a specified delimiter.

1. All ints before 1st `:` (ex: `9`)
2. All ints after 1st `-` or 2nd space, and before 2nd `:` (ex: `12`)
3. All chars before 3rd space (ex: `9:30AM - 12:50PM`)
4. All chars before the last space and after 2nd to last space (ex: `AbCdEfGhIj`)

Right now I'm able to get the following:

```
REGEXP_SUBSTR(A.FIELD, '\S*$')                        -- XY-000
REGEXP_SUBSTR(A.UP_CLASS_MEETINGS, '[^ ]+', 1)        -- 9:30AM
```

Is my second example to get `9:30AM` the best method? Is it flawed?

How can I best utilize `SUBSTR`, `INSTR`, and/or `REGEXP_SUBSTR`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
regexp_substr(a.field, '(\d+):', 1, 1, '', 1),
regexp_substr(a.field, '(\d+):', 1, 2, '', 1),
regexp_substr(a.field, '\S+(\s|-)+\S+'),
regexp_substr(a.field, '\S+(\s|-)+\S+\s+(.*)\s+\S+$', 1, 1, '', 2)
```

[fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/806f1/5)

Comment: Thanks, works great with the exception of the last line. I've edit my post.

Comment: I apply the 4th one: SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR ('Tag: XXXX (TEM4B19318D ) Type: TRIP ONLY Removed from: POINT S_BAY CAPBNK 7F94 SW',  '\sCAPBNK\s(\w+)\s', 1, 1, '', 1) FROM dual; it works like charm with result 7F94 .  Yet, I don't know why it works.  Somebody please explains to me.